# get active colourramp form qgis rasterlayer

Tags: qgis, python

I m building a pythonscript were i need the active singleband pseudocolour colourband of a raster. I want to give the active colourramp a new min and max value.

I can only find examples like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148829/how-to-update-raster-color-ramp-with-new-min-max-values-using-pyqgis) one. In this example they create a new colourramp. But i want to keep the exsiting one.

Does somebody know how i can get the active colour ramp with python?