# Setting 'classificationMode = Continuous' to a raster layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, style

I need to add to this script:

[How to update raster color ramp with new min/max values using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148829/how-to-update-raster-color-ramp-with-new-min-max-values-using-pyqgis)

this function: [QgsColorRampShader](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsColorRampShader.html#ae05ecb31f201de7856aeca256ac3f800) for setting `'classificationMode = Continuous'`, similarly as `setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)`, but I tried it and it doesn't work.

```
    def setStyle(self, layer):
    provider = layer.dataProvider()
    extent = layer.extent()

    stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, extent, 0)

    if stats.minimumValue < 0:
        min = 0
    else:
        min = stats.minimumValue

    max = stats.maximumValue
    range = max - min
    add = range // 2
    interval = min + add

    colDic = {'red': '#ff0000', 'yellow': '#ffff00', 'blue': '#0000ff'}

    valueList = [min, interval, max]

    lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], QColor(colDic['red'])),
           QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], QColor(colDic['yellow'])),
           QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], QColor(colDic['blue']))]

    myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()
    myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

    myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)
    myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
    # TODO: add classificationMode=Continuos
    myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

    myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer.dataProvider(),
                                                        layer.type(),
                                                        myRasterShader)

    layer.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the last [QgsColorRampShader()](http://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsColorRampShader.html) class has not a method that allows setting a classification mode.

Instead, looking at the same [API](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsColorRampShader.html) for the upcoming QGIS 3.0, there is the [setClassificationMode()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsColorRampShader.html#aa0cf88eb94d90a78181b1ba2b60a3e20) module that should do what you are looking for.