# Value labels not showing for raster when styled with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, style, python-2.7

I'm developing a script which includes a function to style raster layers (based on  [Setting 'classificationMode = Continuous' to a raster layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239482) and [Qgis: style a discrete raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194116)). The script executes without any errors and colours the layer correctly. But the styled raster does not show any value labels (see image below).

If I go to the Style tab in Layer Properties and click apply, the values are then shown, so I think I must just be missing some sort of refresh command. My understanding was that `lyr.triggerRepaint()` should take care of this issue. I also tried `iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` but no such luck.

[image: styled layer output]

```
def styleRaster(lyr, lst):
    fcn = QgsColorRampShader()
    fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
    fcn.setColorRampItemList(lst)
    shader = QgsRasterShader()
    shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
    renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(lyr.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
    lyr.setRenderer(renderer)
    lyr.triggerRepaint() 
    return


tciLyr = iface.addRasterLayer(hydroLyrs['tci'])

lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor("#f7fbff")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(4, QColor("#deebf7")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(8, QColor("#c6dbef")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(12, QColor("#9ecae1")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(16, QColor("#6baed6")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(20, QColor("#4292c6")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(24, QColor("#2171b5")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(28, QColor("#08519c")),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(32, QColor("#08306b"))]

styleRaster(tciLyr, lst)
```

Comment: How about `iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(lyr)`?

Comment: thanks @Joseph but that did not work for me either. I still get the same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the value label to the `colourRampItem`. My input list now looks like this:

```
lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor("#f7fbff"),'0'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(4, QColor("#deebf7"),'4'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(8, QColor("#c6dbef"),'8'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(12, QColor("#9ecae1"),'12'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(16, QColor("#6baed6"),'16'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(20, QColor("#4292c6"),'20'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(24, QColor("#2171b5"),'24'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(28, QColor("#08519c"),'28'),\
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(32, QColor("#08306b"),'32')]
```

Comment: Nice one! Your answer may also solve the issue for this post: [refreshLayerSymbology raster layer legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256133/refreshlayersymbology-raster-layer-legend)